# How can I read an object from a typescript file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I have an object located in a typescript file defined as:

```
export const someObject = {
  value1: 'hello',
  value2: 'goodbye',
  value3: '3.4.5'
}
```

I am trying to read this object in nodejs and modify it based on whether the version in package.json was changed. So far in my nodejs script, I have the following:

```
var pjson = require('./package.json');
console.log(pjson.version);
```

Noted, this will only print the version. But if someone can point me in the right direction for how to read an object like the one above not situated in a JSON file, that would be really helpful. From there I would just need to write the new version to `value3` which I am hoping it would be similar to reading from `value3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you can't modify a variable if it's defined as a `const` therefore need to change that to `let` or `var` by:

```
export let someObject = {
  value1: 'hello',
  value2: 'goodbye',
  value3: '3.4.5'
}
```

then import **someObject** by:

```
import { someObject } from './someFile'
```

then update the value every time you start the application

```
someObject.value3 = pjson.version
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I realized after that this was a const variable and I can't modify it. My brain did not work at all before the holidays. But yes converting to a 'let' should definitely work